# Set timeout time works not in all cases in Pyppeteer

Tags: javascript, python, puppeteer, pyppeteer

I set timeout time in Pyppeteer to 60 sec, but it doesn't work for all pages. Here is my code:

```
options = {'timeout': 60 * 1000}
response = await self.page.goto(url, options)
```

I try to load this URL with a timeout: http://www.google.com:81
But after 60 sec it doesn't raise timeout exception. After 4 minutes it raises `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`
How can I set timeout time for pages as I have?

Comment: How do you run your code? Just node? A test runner?

Comment: Just node. I'm planning load pages and save source to DB

Answer (score 1):

the options in pyppeteer need to be set as keyword arguments.

```
page.wait_for_selector('.someclass',timeout= 5000)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Python, duration is calculated using seconds, not microseconds. That is why you have to:

```
options = {'timeout': 60}
response = await self.page.goto(url, options)
```

Comment: I followed your advice and got an error: "Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 60 ms exceeded". So the time is set here in ms, not seconds.